# What is the recommended way to pass Apollo Client around in a React app?

Tags: react-apollo

Right now I am using the HOC `withApollo` like:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withApollo(withData(Browse)));
```

then in that component:

```
  render() {
    const { client } = this.props;
    <Button onPress={() => searchInterestsTab(client)} />
```

then outside that component:

```
export const searchInterestsTab = (client) => {
```

^ but am finding this gets very messy having to pass it into every outside function from my component.

---

Couldn't I just use:

```
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({...})
export default apolloClient;
```

then:

```
import apolloClient from './apolloClient';
```

everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to use it with kind of:

`import apolloClient from './apolloClient'`

If you look at the [usage documantation](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client#usage) you see that you can use it. So somewhere most possible in your `index.js` you should already have

`const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({...})`

My apollo client is instantiated like this:

```js
import ApolloClient, { addTypename } from 'apollo-client';

const createApolloClient = options => {
   return new ApolloClient(Object.assign({}, {
      queryTransformer: addTypename,
      dataIdFromObject: (result) => {
         if (result.id && result.__typename) {
            return result.__typename + result.id;
         }
         return null;
      },
   }, options))
};

export default createApolloClient;
```

and in the `index.js` it is used like this:

```js
...

const client = createApolloClient({
   networkInterface: networkInterface,
   initialState: window.__APOLLO_STATE__,
   ssrForceFetchDelay: 100,
});


....


export {
  client,
  ...
};
```

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot more sense to me. So what's the point of the HOC wrapper 'withApollo'? >.<

Comment: If you use apollo client with your [favorite framework](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client#learn-how-to-use-apollo-client-with-your-favorite-framework) you mostly don't use the HOC. Only on some special cases for example if you have a component which has a mutation as prop. Than you can call the mutation via the HOC